# How to convert the solution of this recurrence like this form?

Tags: output-formatting, sequence

I am trying to solve the recurrence sequence. I tried

```
RSolve[{a[n] == 1/2 (a[n - 1] + 9/a[n - 1]), a[1] == 1}, a[n], 
  n] // Simplify
```

I got

> {{a[n] -> 3 Coth[2^(-1 + n) ArcCoth[1/3]]}}

How to convert this solution to this form

> (3*2^(2^(-1 + n)) + 3)/(2^(2^(-1 + n)) - 1)

Comment: This is not possible for these are entirely different number. One has $a(n) \to 0$ for $n \to \infty$, but $(3 (49 + 49^n))/(-49 + 49^n) \to 3$.

Comment: They are not equal at `n=2` for instance.

Comment: I just realized that the solution $a(n)$ given by Mathematica does not fulfill the recurrence relation...

Comment: @b.gatessucks Edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A way:

```
sol = a[n] /. RSolve[{a[n] == 1/2 (a[n - 1] + 9/a[n - 1]), a[1] == 1}, a[n],n][[1, 1]]  
FullSimplify[sol // TrigToExp // ComplexExpand, Assumptions -> {n > 1, n \[Element] Integers}] // Factor
```

> $\frac{3 \left(2^{2^{n-1}}+1\right)}{2^{2^{n-1}}-1}$

Answer (score 1):

The following verifies your result

```
sol = RSolve[{a[n] == 1/2 (a[n - 1] + 9/a[n - 1]), a[1] == 1}, a[n],n][[1, 1]];
Assuming[n > 1 && n ∈ Integers, (3*2^(2^(-1 + n)) + 3)/(2^(2^(-1 + n)) - 1) == a[n] /.sol // FullSimplify]
```

Note that your second expression has the wrong limiting value for `n=1`.  This may make it harder to find an automatic transformation.